# Is there a Blender equivalent to switch layers in 2D animation?

Tags: modeling, animation, workflow

So, in 2D software like Anime Studio Pro, there's a thing called switch layers. Basically, you draw artwork on various layers, group them, and can then keyframe switching between them. It's an easy way to lip sync, draw each mouth shape individually and then switch between them.

My question is, is there an equivalent method for 3D modelling in Blender? The project I'm planning contains one character who requires a way to model individual heads with different mouth shapes to lip sync (a la this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F25RKt7DldM&t=9m56s). Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: maybe shapekeys? http://www.blender.org/manual/animation/shape_keys.html see also something like https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Advanced_Tutorials/Advanced_Animation/Guided_tour/Mesh/Shape/Sync to get an idea